# how to display current X-Y position of window in gnome-terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, window

For input into `gnome-terminal --geometry`.
I would like to customize the gnome-terminal position upon opening it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be different depending on your OS but lets assume you are using gnome on ubuntu, in which case try the following

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'gnome-terminal --geometry=80x24+100+100'
```

For cinnamon desktop, try the following

```
gsettings set org.cinnamon.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'gnome-terminal --geometry=80x24+100+100'
```